# SQL to distinct part of the string - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `table1` with column `line` which is of type `CLOB`

Here are the values:

```
seq    line
------------------------------
1       ISA*00*TEST
        ISA*00*TEST1
        GS*123GG*TEST*456:EHE
        ST*ERT*RFR*EDRR*EER
        GS*123GG*TEST*456:EHE
-------------------------------
2       ISA*01*TEST
        GS*124GG*TEST*456:EHE
        GS*125GG*TEST*456:EHE
        ST*ERQ*RFR*EDRR*EER
        ST*ERW*RFR*EDRR*EER
        ST*ERR*RFR*EDRR*EER
```

I am trying to find the distinct string of the substring before the second star.

The output would be:

```
distinct_line_value   count
ISA*00                2
GS*123GG              2
ST*ERT                1
ISA*01                1
GS*124GG              1
GS*125GG              1
ST*ERQ                1
ST*ERW                1
ST*ERR                1
```

Any ideas how I can do it based on distinct for the first 2 stars?

Comment: Do those sample values belong to one row (which might be the case, regarding that it is CLOB), or to *many* rows?

Comment: It is all in 1 row.

Comment: Just to be clear - there are many rows, but there are multiple lines in each row.

Comment: I have updated the question to clear it.

Comment: Thank you; it makes things much more clear. I've posted an answer, have a look, please.

Comment: Just asking, Is there anything that you write on your own or rely completely on the benevolence of StackOverflow contributors :-) ?

Comment: I'm not able to understand, if you don't want to help, you can just ignore my questions. Why post unnecessary comments? Just FYI - I do ample of other work which I can. I ask only things which I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

Test case:

```
SQL> select * from test;

       SEQ LINE
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 ISA*00*TEST
           ISA*00*TEST1
           GS*123GG*TEST*456:EHE
           ST*ERT*RFR*EDRR*EER
           GS*123GG*TEST

         2 ISA*01*TEST
           GS*124GG*TEST*456:EHE
           GS*125GG*TEST*456:EHE
           ST*ERQ*RFR*EDRR*EER
           ST*E
```

Query (see comments within the code; apart from that `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is crucial here, along with its `'m'` match parameter which treats the input string as multiple lines):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- split CLOB values to rows
  3  inter as
  4    (select seq,
  5       regexp_substr(line, '^.*$', 1, column_value, 'm') res
  6     from test,
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= regexp_count(line, chr(10)) + 1
  9                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10    ),
 11  -- convert CLOB to VARCHAR2 (so that SUBSTR works)
 12  inter2 as
 13    (select to_char(res) res From inter)
 14  -- the final result
 15  select substr(res, 1, instr(res, '*', 1, 2)) val, count(*)
 16  from inter2
 17  group by substr(res, 1, instr(res, '*', 1, 2))
 18  order by 1;

VAL                                                  COUNT(*)
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
GS*123GG*                                                   2
GS*124GG*                                                   1
GS*125GG*                                                   1
ISA*00*                                                     2
ISA*01*                                                     1
ST*ERQ*                                                     1
ST*ERR*                                                     1
ST*ERT*                                                     1
ST*ERW*                                                     1

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: It is taking a really long time to process my 30K records. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Values you stored into a CLOB certainly don't help. 30K rows either. Regular expressions as well. Therefore, quite a few *drawbacks* you have to deal with. If you could redesign the data model and store every row (which is now part of a CLOB) into its own column (row), possibly into a VARCHAR2 column, you'd have a simple `select substr(line, 1, up_to_the_2nd_*), count(*) ... group by substr...` and enjoy the speed of light. If not, as far I can tell, you'll have to live with its slowness.